# Exporting C# Lists to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on converting large data collection text files to excel. I have been able to successfully read-in and manipulate a text file, but am having difficulty on exporting it to excel.

I currently have data like coordinates in separate lists (x coordinate in a list, y coordinates in another list), I want it so that when the data is viewed in excel that the `x` and `y` coordinates are displayed in separate columns. I have looked online and saw a lot of people recommend `DataGridView`, but I am not familiar with it, and after reading the documentation, still don't understand it. I was wondering what the best approach is to convert these lists into columns in an excel file. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: If you have a list of your objects to export, bringing a `DataGridView` into the picture appears unnecessary. Simply export the list to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some data in `list` objects, you should be able to create Excel files as described in [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp).